# How to refresh Gallery after deleting image from SDCard

Tags: android, android-mediascanner

When deleting the images on Android’s SD Card, sometimes the images are correctly removed but in the gallery still remains a preview of the removed image. When tapping on it, it is loaded as a black image. To resolve it I need to run `MediaScanner`. But this code doesn't work and still, the preview of review image remains in the Gallery.

Anyone knows how to resolve this.

```
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,contentUri); 
sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should delete it from mediaStore

```
public static void deleteFileFromMediaStore(final ContentResolver contentResolver, final File file) {
    String canonicalPath;
    try {
        canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        canonicalPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    final Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    final int result = contentResolver.delete(uri,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[] {canonicalPath});
    if (result == 0) {
        final String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        if (!absolutePath.equals(canonicalPath)) {
            contentResolver.delete(uri,
                    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{absolutePath});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The application's ContentResolver (retrieved as context.getContentResolver())

Comment: Your code works for android 4.3, But in android 4.4 it still show removed image preview in the gallery

Comment: This seems to work like a charm when I tested it on 4.1 and 5.1 since I have only these two devices.. not sure about 4.4.

Comment: This code is not working in Marshmallow devices. Any idea?

Comment: @Nithinjith For me M is working. Make a new question on stack.

Answer (score 10):

Although

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

is restricted for only system apps from 4.4

here is the another solution..pass the path of the image you have deleted or added and if the image is deleted image pass `true` or if added image to gallery then pass `false`.

```
    /**
 * Scanning the file in the Gallery database
 * 
 * @param path
 * @param isDelete
 */
private void scanFile(String path, final boolean isDelete) {
    try {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { path },
                null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        if (isDelete) {
                            if (uri != null) {
                                context.getContentResolver().delete(uri,
                                        null, null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your code but still it show the preview of removed image in the gallery. Any clue why its not working. I am testing the app in android 4.3 & above

Comment: @AndroidDev this is the only way now.. works fine for me.pass the true if the image is deleted..

Comment: Ok I will let u know.

Comment: This is how i used your code, Here it always return null value for the Uri. Can u check what actually wrong in my code. I am testing on Note2 (Android version 4.3) http://pastebin.com/iikBbaP8

Comment: @AndroidDev seems to be okay..for my sake once try getPath instead of getAbsolutePath

Comment: I tried using getPath(), but not working, in which version of android device u r testing

Comment: I am also testing on kitkat and JB. So whats the issue why its returning null in the URI

Comment: @AndroidDev uri is null but image is removed from the gallery..there is no black thumb also

Comment: But in my case it still show in the gallery. Can u send me the sample example in my mail anshu_bora_2006@yahoo.com.

Comment: After lot of trial & error. finally fix the issue. Thanks a lot man. Can I get your mail ID, So that we can discuss our problems.

Comment: @AndroidDev how did you fix it ?

Comment: Exactly the same issue I am facing. I use mediaScanner to refresh the gallery. After scanning process completes the preview of the image is deleted. Please help. @AndroidDev

Comment: @AndroidDev  can u pls tell me how u resolve your issue i m also facing same issue

Comment: On Android 6.0.1, after a file delete and subsequent scan,  `onScanCompleted()` triggers with uri = null. So obviously this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

For each file while deleted use this

> KITKAT

this worked for me

```
try {
            context.getContentResolver().delete(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='"
                            + new File(fileUri).getPath() + "'", null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Add this to your manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
            <data android:scheme="file" /> 
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: This code doesn't work in android 4.4. It crash and show the following logcat Permission Denial：Not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED

Comment: Nope it still crash in android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for C# Xamarin Code and found this for Xamarin-Android

> You can pass multiple deleted Files addresses/path to **ScanFile(Context,string[])** so the Mediascanner gets inform and update the gallery

```
 Android.Media.MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Android.App.Application.Context, new string[] { deletedImageFilePath}, null, null);
```