# How do i completely delete file (image)

Tags: java, android, refresh, gallery, delete-file

I'm trying to delete an image from my gallery:

```
 file.delete()
```

and the file was not completely deleted - when I check if the file exists:

```
 file.exists()
```

It return false but if I get into the gallery I can see that instead the image there is an empty image (like an error). But if I restarting my device the image completely delete! 
so my question is: How can I refresh the gallery?

Comment: file should be used by another process therefore it is not deleted....

Comment: What boolean value does `delete()` return for you?

Comment: @Sumit so what should I do?

Comment: @Taras B it returns "true"

Comment: @PHPupil if it gives `true` then the image is truly deleted. The thing now is how Gallery app reacts on that. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606080/how-to-refresh-gallery-after-deleting-image-from-sdcard how people propagate the change to media apps.

Comment: @Taras It doesnt work for me..

Comment: The file is completely deleted ofcourse. Not partially. But Gallery app uses a thumbnail generated by the media store. So only when the media store is aware of a file delete it will not show the picture anymore. This is for instance after a reboot.

Comment: @greenapps i understand, there is more actions for "media store is aware of a file delete it will not show the picture anymore"?

Answer (score 0):

I work in my computer,there is not this problem,when i use file.delete(), the file can be completely deleted. And my environment is jdk 1.7_0_51. so i think it's maybe a version error

Comment: no.. my environment is jdk 1.8_0_20.. maybe i will try my app with another device (with another android version).. @Peng Zhang