# ContentResolver doesn't contain just created image in an immediate query after creation of file

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, storage-access-framework, documentfile

I'm using this code to copy an image using `documentFile.createFile()`

```
private void newcopyFile(File fileInput, String outputParentPath,
                            String mimeType, String newFileName) {

        DocumentFile documentFileGoal = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);

        String[] parts = outputParentPath.split("\\/");
        for (int i = 3; i < parts.length; i++) {
            if (documentFileGoal != null) {
                documentFileGoal = documentFileGoal.findFile(parts[i]);
            }
        }
        if (documentFileGoal == null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        DocumentFile documentFileNewFile = documentFileGoal.createFile(mimeType, newFileName);

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(documentFileNewFile.getUri());
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileInput);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                }
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                inputStream = null;
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                outputStream = null;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is how I query `ContentResolver` after creating image, to immediately refresh my image gallery with the result of query which should contain info of newly created image.

```
cursorPhotos = MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projectionsImages,
                    null,
                    null,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"
            );
```

But immediate query couldn't find newly created image.
And if I run query again after a moment, newly created image is there in the result.

It seems providing information for newly created image takes time for `ContentResolver`(if ContentResolver is in charge for it) as it would be running in background while I run immediate query.

Is there any method or listener to know when the newly created image is registered by `ContentResolver`?

Comment: Are you copying the images inside a Async Task or on the main UI Thread?

Comment: @Rahulrr2602 Yes, see the answer.

Comment: Thank You very much. If I loop the newcopyFile method many times then sometimes the documentFileGoal is null.

Comment: You're welcome. Copy and paste your code on a new question then direct me to your question's link.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have asked a new question . This is the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/45263806/7317019 . Any help would be really grateful.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have asked a new question . This is the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/45263806/7317019 . Any help would be really grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [this](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/use-contentobserver-to-listen-to-changes/) or this is how I've implemented a listener(observer) to `ContentResolver` changes, using `ContentObserver` to know when is the appropriate time to run a query for getting newly created image from `ContentResolver`.

First create `ContentObserver` Class:

This class as its name tells us, observes any content changes in our desired Uri.

```
class MyObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public MyObserver(android.os.Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        this.onChange(selfChange, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        //(SDK>=16)
        // do s.th.
        // depending on the handler you might be on the UI
        // thread, so be cautious!

        // This is my AsyncTask that queries ContentResolver which now
        // is aware of newly created media file.
        // You implement your own query here in whatever way you like
        // This query will contain info for newly created image
        asyncTaskGetPhotosVideos = new AsyncTaskGetPhotosVideos();
        asyncTaskGetPhotosVideos.execute();
    }
}
```

and at the end of your copy method, you could set `ContentObserver` to your `ContentResolver` on specific Uri.

```
 getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
         MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
         true,
         myObserver);
```

and don't forget to unregister your observer otherwise you will face memory leak. I would prefer to do it at the end of my AsyncTask (onPostExecute).

```
getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(myObserver);
```

You could choose to have a `ContentObserver` on your desired Uri through your entire app lifecycle to get notified whenever a media got changed, deleted or inserted from outside or within your app.

For this approach, you could register your observer in the `onResume()` lifecycle method and unregister it in the `onPause()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i posted wrong code

When you add files to Android’s filesystem these files are not picked up by the MedaScanner automatically. But often they should be.

So to add a file to content provider manually

So use this code :-

```
Intent intent =
      new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

For more methods of doing this and for reference visit this site:-

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-files-to-androids-media-library-using-the-mediascanner/

Comment: Why would I need to delete an item from media store? I just need a listener for `ContentResolver` refreshing is done.

Comment: File was added but `ContentProvider` wasn't aware of it which I guess it's active (probably searching all media files and other stuff) to provide information for newly created media. So I just needed an Observer (`ContentObserver`) to get to know when `ContentResolver` is done with getting newly created image. See my answer and provided link. Thanks by the way.